# Boost Library Server/Client

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, server, boost-asio

This is my Server side Code using boost library.

```
private:
  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
    std::string input= data_;


    if(input=="ls"){
        path p = current_path();
          directory_iterator it{p};

          while (it != directory_iterator{})
            {
              input.append(it->path().string());
              //const directory_entry& entry = *it++;

              it++;

          }
          std::cout <<input << std::endl;
          std::cout <<input.length() << std::endl;

        }

    else if(input=="cp")
 {
        input="pc";
  }
    else if(input=="rm")
   {
        input="mr";
    }
    else
        {
            input= "llo";
        }
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(input, (input.length())),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
     memset(data_, 0, max_length);
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }
```

This is the Client site Code

```
    while(1)
    {
    std::cout << "Enter message: ";
    char request[max_length];
    std::cin.getline(request, max_length);
    size_t request_length = std::strlen(request);
    boost::asio::async_write(s,
        boost::asio::buffer(request, request_length),
        boost::bind(&handle_write,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    char reply[2048];
   boost::asio::read(s,
      boost::asio::buffer(reply, 163));

    std::cout << "Reply is: ";
    std::cout<<reply<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "\n";

    }
  }
```

What my code is doing?
Client sents request to server, server process it and sends it back.
For example if client send `ls` , the server code goes into first if and than performs ls command on Server and sends the output back to client.

when I am sending back there is a problem with input.lenght.
Server code here

```
boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(input, (input.length())),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
     memset(data_, 0, max_length);
```

if I put exact length that is 163 it is displaying perfect result but I don't want to fix because I never know what size it sends.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(input, (input.length())),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
     memset(data_, 0, max_length);
In this code input.lenght() is not working fine. it is working fine when I give the exact length that is 163 of the output. I don't get what the problem with buffer